# Adding class to clicked (nested) div element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

Recently I am fiddling a bit with jQuery and I can't solve the following issue after trying multiple solutions:

I have some inner div's which function as buttons. The button div should get an css `active` class when the button is pressed and it should remove the `active` class on the other buttons. The `active` class simple makes the button highlighted.

The bit of jQuery I came up with up till now is based of a post which was an example for some `Semantic-ui` buttons (I am also using `Semantic-Ui`). This however does not work for my specific case.

The part I have up till now is as follow:

```
button = {};

    // ready event
    button.ready = function () {

        // selector cache
        var
            $buttons = $('.topOrders');

            // alias
            handler = {
                activate: function () {
                    $(this)
                        .addClass('active')
                        .siblings()
                        .removeClass('active')
                        ;
                }
            };

        $buttons
            .on('click', handler.activate);

    };


    // attach ready event
    $(document)
        .ready(button.ready);
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="topOrders">
    <div class="vertical">
        <div class="ui button right labeled" tabindex="0">
            <div class="opsOrder ui button right pointing label">
                <i class="file alternate icon"></i> Test
            </div>
            <a class="ui basic label">
                1234
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vertical">
        <div class="ui button right labeled" tabindex="0">
            <div class="opsOrder ui button right pointing label">
                <i class="file alternate icon"></i> Test
            </div>
            <a class="ui basic label">
                1234
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery code however adds the active class to the container class `topOrders`.

The buttons are actually button `div's` with a label besides them, the actual button is this part:

```
<div class="opsOrder ui button right pointing label">
    <i class="file alternate icon"></i> Test
</div>
```

I tried several things like

```
if ($('.topOrders').hasClass('opsOrder')) {
    //.addClass logic
}
```

and

```
.closest('.opsOrder').addClass('active')
```

Comment: `addClass('active')` will add the *class* `active`, not the pseudo-class `:active`. Not the main problem though, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery is adding to the the container class `topOrders` because that's what you tether your event handler to with `$buttons = $('.topOrders');`.

So if you want the event handler to only work on the label part of the button you should be more specific with your selector. For example, you can select by multiple classes to get the inner div `$buttons = $('.button.label');`.

If you want the event handler on this outer `topOrders` div but you only want the button to change class. You need to change the `activate` function instead of targeting `$(this)` should target `$('.button.label')`